# upload folder suddenly not writable

Tags: php, content-management-system

I've been using a CMS I found online for almost a year (Secretary) with no problem until very recently, when checking up on it gave me an error. I logged into my CMS and I had 
alerts that said " files cannot be uploaded because the folder is not writable."

I haven't touched anything (code, folders, etc) in the past year, so I don't really know where to start troubleshooting. I checked folder permissions and all folders were at 0755 and files were at 0644. Also tried using chmod, but that did not work at all. Also tried contacting Hostgator's live chat, but they were incredibly unhelpful because my package does not include tech support.

Any ideas on what has happened? Thank you!

Comment: Did you searched on Google?

Comment: are those files being created from script?

Comment: @manetsus Yes I did. Everything that popped up had something to dowith file permissions, and when I tested the folders to see if they were writable, they were, but my CMS does not seem to be able to write on it.

Comment: @FerozAkbar In a way, yes, because it's a portfolio so I had to put descriptions and such, but I haven't done anything to it recently.